# Segformer: IndexError: Target 151 is out of bounds

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, index-error

I've been working on this Segformer (using transformers for image segmentation) I've been having issues with getting a message stating that the target is out of bounds.

So here is the code that I am using.

```
!pip install --upgrade transformers

!nvidia-smi

from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from transformers import AdamW
import torch
from torch import nn
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
import os
from PIL import Image
from transformers import SegformerForSemanticSegmentation, 
SegformerFeatureExtractor
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import numpy as np
import albumentations as aug

os.getcwd()
```

ok, from here this is my current working directoy:
'/data/users/me/Rugd_dataset'
My images are stored in two folders one called images, the nest mask. Each have a sub directory of test and train

```
    WIDTH = 512
    Height = 512

    class ImageSegmentationDataset(Dataset):

    """Image segmentation dataset."""
    
    def __init__(self, root_dir, feature_extractor, transforms=None, train=True):
        """
        Args:
            root_dir (string): Root directory of the dataset containing the images + annotations.
            feature_extractor (SegFormerFeatureExtractor): feature extractor to prepare images + segmentation maps.
            train (bool): Whether to load "training" or "validation" images + annotations.
        """
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.feature_extractor = feature_extractor
        self.train = train
        self.transforms = transforms
    
        sub_path = "train" if self.train else "test"
        self.img_dir = os.path.join(self.root_dir, "images", sub_path)
        self.ann_dir = os.path.join(self.root_dir, "mask", sub_path)
    
     # read images
            image_file_names = []
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.img_dir):
                image_file_names.extend(files)
            self.images = sorted(image_file_names)
            
            # read annotations
            annotation_file_names = []
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.ann_dir):
                annotation_file_names.extend(files)
            self.annotations = sorted(annotation_file_names)
    
            assert len(self.images) == len(self.annotations), "There must be as many images as there are segmentation maps"

     def __len__(self):
            return len(self.images)
    
     def __getitem__(self, idx):
            
            image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(self.img_dir, 
self.images[idx]))
                image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
           segmentation_map = cv2.imread(os.path.join(self.ann_dir, self.annotations[idx]))
           segmentation_map = cv2.cvtColor(segmentation_map, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            
    #         image = Image.open()
    #         segmentation_map = Image.open()
    
        if self.transforms is not None:
            augmented = self.transforms(image=image, mask=segmentation_map)
            # randomly crop + pad both image and segmentation map to same size
            encoded_inputs = self.feature_extractor(augmented['image'], augmented['mask'], return_tensors="pt")
        else:
            encoded_inputs = self.feature_extractor(image, segmentation_map, return_tensors="pt")
    
        for k,v in encoded_inputs.items():
            encoded_inputs[k].squeeze_() # remove batch dimension
    
        return encoded_inputs

transform = aug.Compose([
    aug.Flip(p=0.5)
])

dir_path = r'images/train'
count = 0
# Iterate directory
for path in os.listdir(dir_path):
    # check if current path is a file
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, path)):
        count += 1
print('File count:', count)
```

current count = File count: 7386

```
dir_path = r'mask/train'
count = 0
# Iterate directory
for path in os.listdir(dir_path):
    # check if current path is a file
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, path)):
        count += 1
print('File count:', count)
```

this is what I receive as a File count: 7386.  So my paths to the images seem to fit.

```
root_dir = '/data/users/christopher.kehl/Rugd_dataset'
feature_extractor = SegformerFeatureExtractor(align=False, reduce_zero_label=False)

train_dataset = ImageSegmentationDataset(root_dir=root_dir, feature_extractor=feature_extractor, transforms=transform)
valid_dataset = ImageSegmentationDataset(root_dir=root_dir, feature_extractor=feature_extractor, transforms=None, train=False)

print("Number of training examples:", len(train_dataset))
print("Number of validation examples:", len(valid_dataset))
```

Number of training examples: 7387
Number of validation examples: 100

```
encoded_inputs = train_dataset[-1]
```

so the index here is supposed to be zero, but I can only get this to work with a 1 or an -1, anything other than 0.

```
encoded_inputs["pixel_values"].shape
```

torch.Size([3, 512, 512])

```
encoded_inputs["labels"].shape
```

torch.Size([512, 512])

```
encoded_inputs["labels"].shape
```

torch.Size([512, 512])

```
encoded_inputs["labels"].squeeze().unique()
```

tensor([ 29,  60,  76,  91, 107])

mask = encoded_inputs["labels"].numpy()

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(mask)
```

shows the images of a mask

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True)

valid_dataloader = DataLoader(valid_dataset, batch_size=4)
batch = next(iter(train_dataloader))

for k,v in batch.items():
    print(k, v.shape)
```

pixel_values torch.Size([4, 3, 512, 512])
labels torch.Size([4, 512, 512])

```
batch["labels"].shape
```

torch.Size([4, 512, 512])

```
classes = pd.read_csv('class_dict_seg.csv')['name']
id2label = classes.to_dict()
label2id = {v: k for k, v in id2label.items()}

    model = SegformerForSemanticSegmentation.from_pretrained("nvidia/mit-b5", ignore_mismatched_sizes=True,
                                                             num_labels=len(id2label), id2label=id2label, label2id=label2id,
                                                             reshape_last_stage=True)

    optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=0.00006)
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model.to(device)
    print("Model Initialized!")

for epoch in range(1, 11):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
    print("Epoch:", epoch)
    pbar = tqdm(train_dataloader)
    accuracies = []
    losses = []
    val_accuracies = []
    val_losses = []
    model.train()
    for idx, batch in enumerate(pbar):
        # get the inputs;
        pixel_values = batch["pixel_values"].to(device)
        labels = batch["labels"].to(device)

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward
        outputs = model(pixel_values=pixel_values, labels=labels)
# evaluate
upsampled_logits = nn.functional.interpolate(outputs.logits, size=labels.shape[-2:], mode="bilinear", align_corners=False)
predicted = upsampled_logits.argmax(dim=1)

mask = (labels != 255) # we don't include the background class in the accuracy calculation
pred_labels = predicted[mask].detach().cpu().numpy()
true_labels = labels[mask].detach().cpu().numpy()
accuracy = accuracy_score(pred_labels, true_labels)
loss = outputs.loss
accuracies.append(accuracy)
losses.append(loss.item())
pbar.set_postfix({'Batch': idx, 'Pixel-wise accuracy': sum(accuracies)/len(accuracies), 'Loss': sum(losses)/len(losses)})

# backward + optimize
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
else:
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for idx, batch in enumerate(valid_dataloader):
            pixel_values = batch["pixel_values"].to(device)
            labels = batch["labels"].to(device)

        outputs = model(pixel_values=pixel_values, labels=labels)
        upsampled_logits = nn.functional.interpolate(outputs.logits, size=labels.shape[-2:], mode="bilinear", align_corners=False)
        predicted = upsampled_logits.argmax(dim=1)

        mask = (labels != 255) # we don't include the background class in the accuracy calculation
        pred_labels = predicted[mask].detach().cpu().numpy()
        true_labels = labels[mask].detach().cpu().numpy()
        accuracy = accuracy_score(pred_labels, true_labels)
        val_loss = outputs.loss
        val_accuracies.append(accuracy)
        val_losses.append(val_loss.item())

print(f"Train Pixel-wise accuracy: {sum(accuracies)/len(accuracies)}\
     Train Loss: {sum(losses)/len(losses)}\
     Val Pixel-wise accuracy: {sum(val_accuracies)/len(val_accuracies)}\
     Val Loss: {sum(val_losses)/len(val_losses)}")
```

Here is the error Block:
IndexError: Target 151 is out of bounds.

Full Trace

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-50d0deee01ff> in <module>
     16 
     17         # forward
---> 18         outputs = model(pixel_values=pixel_values, labels=labels)
     19 
     20         # evaluate

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/models/segformer/modeling_segformer.py in forward(self, pixel_values, labels, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    807                 )
    808                 loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=self.config.semantic_loss_ignore_index)
--> 809                 loss = loss_fct(upsampled_logits, labels)
    810 
    811         if not return_dict:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
   1150         return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
   1151                                ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction,
-> 1152                                label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)
   1153 
   1154 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   2844     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2845         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2846     return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
   2847 
   2848 

IndexError: Target 150 is out of bounds.
```

Comment: Please post the full error trace. Also, what is this value: `num_labels=len(id2label)`?

Comment: I have added my full error trace to the code.

Comment: also, num_labels = 24

Comment: Well, you have 24 labels but some of your labels are idx 107! Can you see the issue?

Comment: I see 107 located in this code block  
                     encoded_inputs["labels"].squeeze().unique()                                 
                                                                                          
I'm not for sure how to fix this.

Comment: Either have a dictionary which converts your labels to idx: `label2id = {v: idx for idx,(k, v) in enumerate(id2label.items())}`, or make your model have more outputs `num_labels=id2label.values().max()`

Comment: I have added the following code and received the same messages`classes = pd.read_csv('class_dict_seg.csv')['name']
id2label = classes.to_dict()
label2id = {v: idx for idx,(k, v) in enumerate(id2label.items())}
#label2id = {v: k for k, v in id2label.items()}
num_labels=id2label.values()` trace error `IndexError: Target 29 is out of bounds.`